# Is it possible that a user can access his user account from Main PC to another LAN PC in WIN 7?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, remote-access

Is it possible to access a User account/s from a PC say "A" to another PC say "B" through LAN.

I don't want just File Sharing, but want like I have PC "A" on PC "B"..

Comment: You can use the RDP client built into windows. https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/17463/windows-7-connect-to-another-computer-remote-desktop-connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

note that on windows it has a limit only one user can be connected either on RDP or physically logged on. But it works like a charm.